# Why might my wget install of wordpress be failing?

Tags: linux, wordpress, wget

I'm on CentOS 7. I'm running this command:

`wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz`

This is the returned output:

```
--2016-09-08 15:53:04--  http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
Resolving wordpress.org (wordpress.org)... 66.155.40.250, 66.155.40.249
Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|66.155.40.250|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|66.155.40.249|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

I'm not sure why that might be. I have access to my local network from my machine; I can install `yum` packages without issue.

### EDIT

Result of `ip route get 66.155.40.249`

`RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

My /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno16777736 after I edited it:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.2.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eno16777736
UUID=*random*
DEVICE=eno16777736
ONBOOT=yes
```

With the exception of my UUID... Specifically I added: bootproto, ipadder, netmask, and nm_controlled.

Comment: can you provide the output of `ip route get 66.155.40.250` and `ip route get 66.155.40.249`?

Answer (score 0):

This situation happens when no entry in the routing table has been found.
If you're using a laptop (with wifi and ethernet) this may happen if you `dhclient -r` from one interface, which can remove the default route.

Easy resolution:

- make a new dhcp request (optionally release the current lease)
- add the default route by hand: `ip route add default via <<GW ip>>`. If you have several interfaces, you may need to specify the output interface using `ip route add default via <<GW ip>> dev <<devname>>` instead.

Comment: Do you think this might have resulted from my editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno16777736`? I was attempting to get a static IP for my vm.